# Get Count of contacts from case related Account Objects?

Tags: case, account, contact

I'm having a field on case object. I should populate the value of a Related Account related Contact records. Can I do this without writing a trigger?
Rollup Summary field isn't enabled in the case object since I don't have MasterDetail Relationship

Comment: I think this is not possible without a trigger or event better using process builder.

Comment: You mean to say Can I Use Process Builder?

Comment: Process Builder is not a good solution for your scenario. You have two options 1. Write an Apex trigger on both parent and child 2. Use AppExchaneg app rollup helper https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI